# Команда отключения виртуальной машины Linux

Tags: linux, centos, virtualbox, виртуальная-машина

Установил виртуальную машину ( https://www.1c-bitrix.ru/download/vmbitrix.php )

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом можно выключить машину, используя консоль CentOS?

Comment: В centos `sudo halt`

Comment: @PavelGridin а `sudo` обязательно?

Comment: `init 0` попробуйте

Comment: @tirelessfinder, `halt` только от root можно, да без `sudo` можно `poweroff`